# How can I define something and save it in HashMap

Tags: java

I have a Question about the Topic how can I save in HashMap. I have 2 ArrayLists and in the first ArrayList I have some Pizzanames. In the other ArrayList I have the ingredients. I want to define now that for example the Pizza Salami has the ingredients salami, cheese, tomatoes and the Pizzabread. Then I want to save that in a HashMap.

Can anyone Help me?

I have this ArrayLists :

```
List<Pizza> pizzaEntries= new ArrayList<>();
List<Ingredients> ingredientsEntries= new ArrayList();

pizzaEntries.add(new Pizza("Salami",3.50);<-- 3.50=price
ingredientsEntries.add(new Ingredients("cheese",0.50);
ingredientsEntries.add(new Ingredients("Salami", 1.50);
ingredientsEntries.add(new Ingredients("Pickles", 0.50);
ingredientsEntries.add(new Ingredients("Thuna", 1.50);
```

How can i define now that the Pizza Salami has the ingredients cheese and Salami

Comment: Please let us know what have to tried till now ? What is the exception you are getting ? Also, remove  `primefaces` tag since it has no relation with the question. Please refer below link for how to ask a question on Stackoverflow : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can use a HashMap<String, List<String>> with key=pizzaname and value=List of ingredients.

Comment: @Arthi, you need to add your comment as part of the question - it is not readable and not formatted.

Comment: @Arthi Please see the answer and let me know in case of further issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define Ingredients as a class below:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class Ingredients
{
  private Map<String, Double> aIngredientTypeToCost = new HashMap<>();



  public void put(String theType, Double theCost)
  {
    aIngredientTypeToCost.put(theType, theCost);
  }



  public Set<String> getAllIngredientsType()
  {
    return aIngredientTypeToCost.keySet();
  }

}
```

then in the main class you can create a map of type pizza to Ingredients.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class pizza
{

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    Map<String, Ingredients> aMap = new HashMap<>();

    Ingredients aHawaiPizza = new Ingredients();
    aHawaiPizza.put("Salami", 3.50);
    aHawaiPizza.put("Cheeze", 1.50);

    aMap.put("Hawai", aHawaiPizza);

    Ingredients aXyzPizza = new Ingredients();
    aXyzPizza.put("Pickles", 0.50);
    aXyzPizza.put("Thuna", 2.50);

    aMap.put("aXyzPizza", aXyzPizza);

    for( Entry<String, Ingredients> aType : aMap.entrySet() )
    {
      String aPizza = aType.getKey();
      Ingredients aIngredients = aType.getValue();

      System.out.println("A pizza " + aPizza + " has ingredients " + aIngredients.getAllIngredientsType());
    }

  }
}
```